# What weird non-font is this text?

Tags: html

This sounds like the dumbest question, but what font is used on this webpage?

http://aquey.info/loaded-broccoli-potato-soup/

If it copy-pastes the same, then it's like this text here:

I checked using DevTools, of course, but I don't think it's really a ... font? If I copy-paste the text into Gmail and choose "remove formatting", the text still looks like same, like Gmail doesn't see it as text. Gmail also doesn't spellcheck within the text. Notepad++ also doesn't un-format the text and View>Summary counts each letter as a word.

I'm seeing if it's possible to read this text in javascript (that's the programming bit), but right now I just want to understand what it is.

Comment: https://unicodeplus.com/U+1D62E

Comment: https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html

Answer (score 3):

They are Unicode glyphs, specifically from the Unicode block [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols).

As the name implies, they are intended for use within mathematics contexts but are commonly abused in places like social media where other formatting controls are not available to end users.

This may go without saying (and, I fully admit, outside the scope of the question), but it's worth mentioning to future readers that this is extremely counterintuitive to use such glyphs in any context other than their intended use as they [pose a huge accessibility problem](https://bighack.org/accessibility-screen-readers-special-characters-and-unicode-symbols/). It’s especially arbitrary in this particular context when styling the text in question with CSS would net an extremely similar visual effect while preserving usability for screen readers.

Comment: These copy protection schemes, especially in the machine learning era, are almost always facepalms of some (or many) sorts. Methinks someone more concerned with copy/pasting one-offs is probably not as concerned with accessibility, but I could be proven wrong I suppose.